# SQL Server 2008 table-valued function speed

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server 2008 function that returns a temp table
The function executes very fast in Management Studio but it is slow in application

If we run this function in the Management Studio once.
Then the application will speed up for some time

Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like the first time round it's having to work out the execution plan and after that it's got it cached. Perhaps update your stats and take a look at the state of the index defragmentation?

Comment: Could be that you find something useful here. [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)